# Loop for subplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, subplot

In Matlab I have a group of variables `V1_01_04:V32_01_04` denoting VialNR, Monitor Number and Day and a timestamp named Time_01_04, im trying to make a subplot containing all the 32 variables but that takes a long time to type in manually so im looking for some help here, i would like to make a for-loop looking something like this:

```
- for V1_01_04:V32_01_04 - 
  subplot(4,8,1:32) - 
plot(Time_01_4,V1_01_04:V32_01_04)
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should attempt show you have researched this issue. Any code you have tried. If you do not try, you will never learn.

Comment: Please don't store your variables like this. I'm assuming you loaded the data in using `eval`, and now pretty much the only way to deal with it all is to use `eval` again. See [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) for a couple reasons not to approach it this way. I highly recommend storing your variables another way to make accessing them later much less of a chore.

Comment: So i have rearranged my data into dataset using "Mon12day2 = dataset ('File','MyRunCtM012.txt');" is it possible to plot the dataset into a subplot?